# Перебор логинов для программы

Tags: python, скрипт, автоматизация, перебор

Kак в обычную программу автоматически подставлять в 2 поля данные из txt файла скриптом на питоне, как оно всё должно взаимодействовать и каков принцип работы.

Comment: Что вы понимаете под обычной программой?

Comment: @Namerek
NordVPN под windows

Comment: @Namerek, `Winapi`, если под виндой сидите. Дальше гуглите, ибо вопрос не про него.

Comment: @icYFTL вопрос не про кого?

Comment: @icYFTL, можно было-бы подискутировать на счет того, что Winapi - программа. Но фиг с ней, к тому-же вы не по адресу ответили

Comment: @Namerek, а может вы?